# How to make XML element required based on other element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Sample 1

```
    <type="LIST">
      <list>
        <list>
            <label> XML file </label>
            <userID> 123 </userID>
        </list>
      </list>
      <locked>false</locked>
      <order>2</order>
    </type>
    <type="LIST">
      <list/>
      <listName>Has listName</listName>
      <locked>false</locked>
      <order>1</order>
    </type>
```

Sample 2:

```
<type="LIST">
  <list>
  </list>
  <locked>false</locked>
  <order>2</order>
</type>
<type="LIST">
  <list/>
  <listName>Has listName</listName>
  <locked>false</locked>
  <order>1</order>
</type>
```

I want `<list>` element to have atleast one `<list>` when it doesn't have `<listName>` element present. 
`<list>` can be empty when `<listName>` is there. How can I do this validation of XML using XSD? 
In this example,error should be thrown for sample 2 on validation.
I'm not able to achieve it. Any idea? 
Thanks in advance :)